# Property 'service' is required when migrate from Spring 2 to Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-remoting

This server context used to work fine with Spring 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="myService" class = "com.example.service.MyServiceFactory" factory-method="getInstance"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="MyService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="myService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.example.service.MyService"/>
    <property name="registryPort" value="1199"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

However when I switch to spring 4.1.6-RELEASE I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'service' is required
    at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteExporter.checkService(RemoteExporter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.prepare(RmiServiceExporter.java:239)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter.afterPropertiesSet(RmiServiceExporter.java:230)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your `MyService:: MyServiceFactory` method is returning `null`. That doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Spring upgrade, based on this evidence. I suggest debugging that method.

Answer (score 0):

By upgrading to Spring 4, a line in MyServiceFactory.getInstance() fails and returns null, hence the error. So the server context was fine, but this error is not entirely unrelated to Spring 4.

I wish they could make the error more obvious, like saying `ERROR: Property "service" receives a null object` is a lot more informative than the current error message.

Comment: The error is correct, it is expecting a property called 'service', it did not got that, but got a null property, or any other property. To generalize the error is 'Property service is required.'